# usage of $1 and $2 in awk

Tags: awk

As I know in awk, $1 and $2 refer to the first and second field of the file . But can $1 and $2 be used to refer the first and second field of a variable .. Such that if session=5 is stored in a variable. Then I would like to have $1 referring to 'session' and $2 to '5' . Thank you

#### Input File

```
session=123
process=90
customer=145
session=123
customer=198
process=90
```

#### CODE

```
 awk '$1 ~ /^Session|^CustomerId/' hi|xargs -L 1 -I name '{if (!($1 SUBSEP $2 in a)) {ids[$1]++; a[$1, $2]}} END {for (id in ids) {print "Count of unique", id, " " ids[id]}}'
```

#### DETAILS

I will pass the output that I got from first and pipe it via xargs and I have the lines read in "name" variable in xargs .. Now my $1 should correspond to first field of xargs and this is my query

#### Output

```
Count of unique sessions=2
Count of unique customer=2
```

Comment: Can you provide the supporting source code that would make that little snippet make sense?

Comment: You'd have to redefine FS and $0 in an action to do something like that.

Comment: I will edit the question with the actual script ..plz refer it

Comment: Could you please look at the code

Comment: @User - can you help us interpret your code?  It appears that you're asking awk to print "Session" and "Customer" fields from the file named "hi", then you're piping the output through xargs, hoping that xargs will run an awk script.  Huh?

Comment: @user - In your sample data, both your `session` lines are equal to 123, so there is only one unique session value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to limit the script to only including "session" and "customer" all you have to do is add the regex to the main script as a selector:

```
awk -F= '$1 ~ /^(session|customer)$/ {if (!($1 SUBSEP $2 in a)) {ids[$1]++; a[$1, $2]}} END {for (id in ids) {print "Count of unique", id, " " ids[id]}}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Field Separator, which can be specified inside the BEGIN code block as `FS="separator"`, or as a command line option to `awk` via `-F "separator"`  This answer shows only the point asked by the question. it does not address the final output.

```
awk -F"=" '$1 == "session" || 
           $1 == "customer" { ids[$1]++ }  # do whatever you need with the counters.
           END { for (id in ids) {
                     print "Count, id "=" ids[id] }}' hi
```

Comment: He didn't ask about unique IDs. He asked about Field Seperators. I've shown him the Field Seperators, ie. $1 and $2. (I've now removed the word Unique from the copy-pasted last line)

Comment: Thanks... That's one word I  get right about 50% of the time :) ... *too many e's, not enough a's*; that may well be the mental association I need...

Answer (score 1):

If what you're looking for is a count of unique customers and sessions, then this might do:

```
awk -F= '
  $1~/^(session|customer)$/ && !seen[$0] {
    seen[$0]=1;
    count[$1]++;
  }
  END {
    printf("Count of sessions: %d\n", count["session"]);
    printf("Count of customers: %d\n", count["customer"]);
  }' hi
```

In addition to keeping a count, this keeps an associative array of lines that have contributed a count, to avoid counting lines a second time - thus making it a unique count.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just try an all `awk` solution? It's more simple:

```
awk -F "=" '$1 ~ /customer|session/ { name[$1]++ } END { for (var in name) print "Count of unique", var"="name[var] }' hi
```

Results:

```
Count of unique customer=2
Count of unique session=2
```

Is there some other reason you need to pipe to `xargs`?

HTH

Comment: I am new to awk and hence I tried xargs .. Anyways I will try to do this .. Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks a lot folks .. i got the output that I needed

Comment: @ghoti, Worth a down vote? Depends a lot on what the op calls `unique`.

Answer (score 0):

Yet an alternative would be

```
awk -F "=" '$1 ~ /customer|session/ {print $1}'|sort |uniq -c | awk '{print "Count of unique "$2"="$1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the answer to the question you deleted:**

This is self-contained AWK script based on an answer of mine to one of your earlier questions:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
/^Customer=/ {
    mc[$0, prev]++
    if (!($0 in cseen)) {
        cust[++custc] = $0
        ids["Customer"]++
    }
    cseen[$0]
}

/^Merchant=/ {
    prev = $0
    if (!($0 in mseen)) {
        merch[++merchc] = $0
        ids["Merchant"]++
    }
    mseen[$0]++
}

END {
    for (id in ids) {
        print "Count of unique", id, ids[id]
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= merchc; i++) {
        merchant = merch[i]
        print "Customers under (" merchant ") is " mseen[merchant]
        for (j = 1; j <= custc; j++) {
            customer = cust[j]
            if (customer SUBSEP merchant in mc) {
                print "(" customer ") under (" merchant ") is " mc[customer, merchant]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Set it be executable and run it:

```
$ chmod u+x customermerchant
$ ./customermerchant data.txt
```